# Eclipse is not able to import JavaFX

Tags: eclipse, archlinux

I just installed the C/C++ Eclipse IDE and afterwards installed the Java programming language plugins. After I tried to create a JavaFX application I noticed that I couldnt import the required JavaFX packages, so I went ahead and installed e(fx)clipse, but it is still not working. Anybody knows how to resolve my problem?

I am using Eclipse Neon.3 and Java 1.8.0_131